# Editable Dictionary<string, BitmapImage> as Resource in different Assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Dictionary<>` of images, and corresponding keys.

```
Dictionary<string, BitmapImage> ImageDictionary { get; set; }
```

The `Dictionary<>` starts with some predefined images, but as the application runs, the user can add more images and keys to the list.

I would like to reference these images in XAML along the lines of ...

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageDictionary['SomeImageKey']" />
```

This seems like a typical requirement, but in the last two hours of googling, I can't seem to find any method that allows me to add to the list, and provide a succinct XAML syntax to reference the images.

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE** ... thanks to @Evk for getting me 99% of the way there!!

In the other assembly that holds the singleton instance of the `Dictionary<string, BitmapImage>`, I have the following:

```
namespace MyOtherAssembly {
public class ImageManager
{

    private ImageManager()
    {
        KeyToImage = new Dictionary<string, BitmapImage>();
        PopulateResourceImages();
    }

    private static readonly Lazy<ImageManager> _Instance = new Lazy<ImageManager>(() => new ImageManager());
    public static ImageManager Instance { get { return _Instance.Value; } }

    public Dictionary<string, BitmapImage> KeyToImage { get; set; }

    public void PopulateResourceImages() { ... }
} }
```

`PopulateResourceImages()` just loads the predefined images.

Now in my user controls, i add the following XAML namespace:

```
xmlns:img="clr-namespace:MyOtherAssembly;assembly=MyOtherAssembly"
```

And then finally in XAML, I add the following binding:

```
            <Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Static img:ImageManager.Instance}, Path=KeyToImage[RightArrowInCircle]}" Width="20" Height="20" />
```

Where `RightArrowInCircle` is one of the keys.

So I now have a dictionary of images, that can be modified and added to, and that has a reasonable XAML syntax.

Is there a better way to do this..?!

Comment: Try a MultiBinding that takes the dictionary and the key by two Bindings.

Comment: why not bind your image to a vm property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind like this (just omit quotes):

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageDictionary[SomeImageKey]}" />
```

Comment: The question seems to be about a dynamic key, i.e. a key of a newly added image, "I can't seem to find any method that allows me to add to the list, and provide a succinct XAML syntax to reference the images."

Comment: @Clemens well if OP confirms this I'll delete an answer. As I understood this - OP cannot find right syntax in xaml to reference by key. But now that you told this - I think you are probably right.

Comment: @Evk - you are right! I couldn't find any information about the `"` delimiterless syntax. I'll update my question with my solution.